# Assembly MIPS %call16(printf)

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this code in Assembly.

```
    .data
tabela:     .word   4, 2, 10, 1, 6
print:      .asciiz "The value is: %d\n"
    .text
    .globl  programa
programa:

    ########################
    Do some stuff here.
    Value on $10 is -99
    ########################


la      $4,print
move    $5,$10
lw      $25,%call16(printf)($28)
jalr    $25
```

This code will print:

```
The value is: -99
```

I understand that:

`la     $4,print` Loads the address of the string to print on the first parameter of function call ($a0)

`move   $5,$10` moves the value on register 10 (in this case -99) to register the second parameter of a function call

And here are my doubts.
I load something on register 25.

What is `%call16(printf)($28)`? It´s what prints the string and the number but I don't understand why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%call16` instructs the assembler to insert an explicit relocation of type R_MIPS_CALL16, which is a 16 bit wide relocation against the GOT entry for the specified function (in your case, `printf`). The relocation basically says "replace the value at offset 0x... with the memory location that symbol printf is stored at". Then `jalr` jumps to the address stored in `$25`.

PS. In some cases (e.g. VxWorks), ELF binaries may not use PIC and then R_MIPS_CALL16 relocations point to an entry in the `.got.plt` section, but that doesn't change your use of the assembler at all.